# Firefox failed to find flash player

Tags: javascript, flash, shockwave

I have the following problem.
JS navigator.plugins suddenly desides, that Shockwave Flash plugin is not installed. Plugin is installed in Firefox (Shockwave Flash 26.0 r0) and set to "always enabled".
I have reinstalled flash plugin (debugger) several times.
What can be the reason?

Comment: You should show the JS you use to detect the plugin.

Comment: I use default "swfobject.js" by when I iterate on navigator.plugins - there is no Shockwave Flash (no matter navigator.plugins returns array or map). Problem is not only in Firefox - Chrome also doesn't return flash plugin.

Comment: You should not iterate instead use namedItem as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorPlugins/plugins

Comment: namedItem also returns null.